# What to eat for people with hay fever or sinus infection

Tags: equipment

Can anyone recommend me some things I can eat when I constantly have sinus infection and can't seem to find anything that would help me minimize the effects.

I am not looking for medication as I already got some by doctor but looking for things like, I heard graphes, or chicken...

Comment: Health questions are off-topic, according to the FAQ.  I recommend complaining to your doctor, and possibly visiting another doctor for a second opinion.

Comment: I have heard that honey sourced from the area to which you are having a reaction can up your resistance, but I can't prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try eating things containing Vitamin C (orange juice, graprefruit, grapes, etc...), and drink hot beverages (tea, green tea, anise, cammomile, etc...), soups also are good (chicken soup is great).

And you have to try to eat healthy foods, for your body to gain strength to resist the bacteria.

Sorry for not adding any references, this is due to my own experience.